# How do I explicitly set %PATH% in System Variable or User Variable in command prompt in a persistent manner?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-command-prompt

When you open sysdm.cpl -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. you can see that envs are divided into two section:

one is `User Variables`, another is `System Variables`, they both have a variable `PATH` in them.

Now if you run `set` inside the `cmd` prompt, it only shows one variable name called `PATH` and it contains the union of the above.

How do I explicitly set `System Variable` or `User Variable` in command prompt in a persistent manner?

Comment: Does it need to be persistent across application starts or does it need to be just for the one session?

Comment: @ElliotLabs I meant to have the same effect like setting one of them in via GUI dialog.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Is PowerShell ok or do you need cmd?

Comment: @ElliotLabs the simpler, the better, cmd would be a finer choice if that is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow [this exhaustive rojo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31889785/3439404) to similar question at StackOverflow: [How to set PATH environment variable in batch file only once on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885906).

Below is a batch/cmd script I formerly wrote to *check* directories in my `%PATH%` as well as in appropriate registry values under `HKLM` and `HKCU`. The script does not write anything in registry; it merely shows another possible approach to such task *in pure batch/cmd* and shows that its solution can't be trivial.

Usage:

- `testpath.bat` (no parameter): *checks* `%PATH%` variable syntax; **a bonus**: shows redundant **duplicities in `%PATH%` variable**;
- `testpath.bat dir` (note *literal* parameter `DIR`): displays a list of executables (as determined in `PATHEXT` variable) for each particular directory in `%PATH%`; **a bonus**: shows redundant and **worthless directories in `%PATH%` variable**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo --- %date% %time% %~nx0 %*  
if /I "%~1" EQU "dir" (
    set path
    Call :printPath path "" dir
    ENDLOCAL
    goto :eof
)

set pathext

Call :duplicity pathext

Call :printPath path ""

rem debugging set "wrongpath=%path%;%SystemRoot%\\"
rem debugging Call :duplicity wrongpath

Call :duplicity path

set "HKCU_type="
set "HKCU_path="
for /F "tokens=2*" %%G in (
  'reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path 2^>NUL ^|findstr /I "path"'
  ) do (
    set "HKCU_type=%%G"
    set "HKCU_path=%%H"
  ) 
Call :printPath HKCU_path %HKCU_type%
if /I "%HKCU_type%"=="REG_EXPAND_SZ" Call :printPath HKCU_path %HKCU_type% Expanded

set "HKLM_type="
set "HKLM_path="
set "qqqq=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
for /F "tokens=2*" %%G in ('reg query "%qqqq%" /v Path^|findstr /I "path"'
  ) do (
    set "HKLM_type=%%G" 
    set "HKLM_path=%%H" 
  ) 
Call :printPath HKLM_path %HKLM_type%
if /I "%HKLM_type%"=="REG_EXPAND_SZ" Call :printPath HKLM_path %HKLM_type% Expanded

:dirOnly
Call :deflatePath HKLM_path %HKLM_type%
    rem echo "!NewPath:%%=%%%%!"

pause
set HK
ENDLOCAL&call set "NewPath=%NewPath%"
goto :eof

:printPath
echo(
echo %~0 %~1 %~2 %~3
if "!%~1!" NEQ "" (
  set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
  rem set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
  for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
    if /I "%~3" NEQ "expanded" (
        if /I "%~3" EQU "dir" (
            echo(
            echo %~0 %~1 %~2 %%~G
            set "_partpath=%%~G"
            if /I "!_partpath:%SystemRoot%=!" EQU "%%~G" (
                dir /B /A:-D "%%~G" | findstr /I "%pathext:;=$ %$"
                rem timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK >NUL
            ) else (
                echo %~0 %~1 %~2 System default 
            )
        ) else (
            echo %%~G
        ) 
    ) else (
        call echo %%~G
    )
  )
  echo(
  echo tested using next findstr regex: 
  echo "%pathext:;=$ %$"
)
goto :eof

:duplicity
echo(
echo %~0 %~1 %~2
set /A "ii=0"
set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
  set /A "ii+=1"
  set /A "jj=0"
  for %%g in (!ggg!) do (
    set /A "jj+=1"
    if /I "%%~G"=="%%~g" if !ii! LSS !jj! echo !ii!, !jj!: %%~g 
  )
)
goto :eof

:deflatePath
echo(
echo %~0 %~1 %~2
set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
rem set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
set "NewPath="
for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
  set "item=%%~G"
  set "meti="
  call :deflateItem "ProgramFiles(x86)"
  if defined meti (
    rem echo # !item!
  ) else (
    call :deflateItem "ProgramFiles"
    if defined meti (
      rem echo # !item!
    ) else (
      call :deflateItem "SystemRoot"
      if defined meti (
        rem echo # !item!
      ) else (
        rem echo = !item:%%=%%%%!
      )
    )
  )
  if defined NewPath (
    set "NewPath=!NewPath!;!item!"
  ) else (
    set "NewPath=!item!"
  )
)
echo !NewPath!
rem reg delete HKCU\Environment /v NewPath /f
rem setx NewPath "!NewPath!"
rem WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
rem reg query HKCU\Environment /v NewPath|findstr /I "NewPath"
goto :eof

:deflateItem
  set "meti=!%~1!"
  if "!meti!"=="!item!" (
    set "item=%%%~1%%"
  ) else (
    set "meti=!item:%meti%\=!"
    if "!meti!" == "!item!" (
      set "meti="
    ) else (
      set "item=%%%~1%%\!meti!"
    )
  )
goto :eof
```

Comment: very rich source of information, but the link you provided seems to only set environment variable for once?